# Gephi: How to create a dynamic graph and change the labels of nodes dynamically?

Tags: graph-visualization, gephi

What I'm trying to do is a visualization of a label propagation algorithm. I need to change the label of a node within certain time and accordingly to that label the node need to assume the color that label.

The trick Gephi part here is how to change the label dynamically from the gexf file so I can set the Gephi to show different colors to different labels or how do I just change the color directly on the file (but accordingly to the time stamp, not in a static way).

I know that question is very specific but I saw some Gephi user around SO before.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a column, e.g. "label" to the node import file, and give numbers according to how you want to "group the nodes into one color". And then you can select to color the nodes via your new column.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [GEXF Primer](http://gexf.net/1.2draft/gexf-12draft-primer.pdf) ou can't have dynamic labels. However you can set a dynamic attribute, and in Gephi you can edit the attribute used as the label (the default attribute is of course "Label").